# Root directory -- verifying ownership -- did I put the file in the right place?

Tags: ftp

down vote favorite
share [fb] share [tw] share [in]

My site is built in PHP.

I need to upload a file to the root directory, to verify ownership of the domain.

I put the file in the first window I see when I log in over ftp, but the file doesn't show up at the relevant url.

Where do I place a file so that it's in the root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will vary since webservers can be setup in different ways. But it should be a directory named one of the following:

- www
- htdocs
- public_html
- wwwroot